# Can't change resolution on MacBook Pro running Windows 10 Boot Camp

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, screen, resolution

I've been running  Windows 10 via Boot Camp on a MacBook Pro 2015 for several months. After a period of inactivity, and a corresponding backlog of updates, I can't change the screen resolution. It's stuck on the highest resolution, 2880 by 1800 pixels (Retina), and the Windows control panel settings are disabled. Is there a remedy?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. As discussed in the article [*If you don‘t see some Mac features when using Windows on your Mac*](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204923), "When you upgrade or reinstall Windows on your Mac, you might need to reinstall or update the Windows support software (drivers) provided by Boot Camp." Note in particular, "If you don't see this option, choose `Action > Download Windows Support Software` from the menu bar." More Boot Camp support downloads may be found [here](https://support.apple.com/downloads/#macoscomponents).

Problems in Windows may include any or all of these:

- Missing screen resolutions.
- Can't adjust brightness.
- Apple input device isn't working.
- Can't hear audio from built-in speakers.
- Built-in microphone or camera isn't recognized.